# Pointer to auto_ptr instead of a classical double pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm quite new to smart pointers and was trying to refactor some existing code to use auto_ptr. The question I have is about double pointers and their auto_ptr equivalent, if that makes sense.

I have a function that accepts a double pointer as its parameter and the function allocates resources for it:

```
void foo ( Image** img ) { ... *img = new Image(); ...}
```

This function is then used like this:

```
Image* img = NULL;
foo ( &img );
...
delete img;
```

I want to use auto_ptr to avoid having to call delete explicitly. Is the following correct?

```
void foo ( auto_ptr<Image>* img ) { ... *img = auto_ptr<Image>(new Image()); ...}
```

and then

```
auto_ptr<Image> img = NULL;
foo ( &img );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does the function do anything with the passed value itself? If not, why not just return an `auto_ptr`?

Comment: Yeah, the function returns a bool indicating if everything has gone right. I guess I could just throw an exception for that...

Comment: ...or return a `NULL` pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::auto_ptr<>` has weird copy semantics (actually it's *move* semantics, rather than copy semantics) and is often not what you want when you want a smart pointer. For example, it cannot be put into STL containers.
If your standard library comes with TR1 support, use `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` instead. (If it doesn't, use [boost's](http://wwww.boost.org) `boost::shared_ptr<>`, which is what `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` was taken from.)

If you want to stick with `std::auto_ptr<>` for your code, you can pass it into the function per non-`const` reference:

```
void foo ( std::auto_ptr<Image>& img ) { ... img.reset(new Image();) ...}

std::auto_ptr<Image> img;
foo ( img );
...
// no need to delete
```

Or you could just return the pointer:

```
std::auto_ptr<Image> foo () {return std::auto_ptr<Image> img(new Image();)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not your STL's implementaton of auto_ptr overrides the '&' operator to return a pointer-to-pointer (most smart pointer classes tend to, but not all auto_ptr implementations do).

If you really want to re-write your code to pass auto_ptr objects around, then you should do something more like this instead, which would be safer:

```
void foo ( std::auto_ptr<Image> &img ) { ... img.reset(new Image()); ...}

std::auto_ptr<Image> img;
foo ( img );
```

Comment: If it would override the unary prefix `&`, it wouldn't be standard-conforming.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are refactoring, I would go one step further and convert the parameter into a return value:

```
// void foo( Image ** img )
std::auto_ptr<Image> foo() {
   std::auto_ptr<Image> tmp( new Image() );
   // ...
   return tmp;
}
```

Even if I prefer removing the requirement from the interface (so that the caller can decide to change the code to use any other type of smart pointer at will):

```
Image* foo() {
   std::auto_ptr<Image> tmp( new Image() );
   // ...
   return tmp.release();
}
int main() {
   std::auto_ptr<Image> ptr( foo() );
}
```